# xtick number with a fixed value

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When drawing with pgfplot in tikz, data maybe change so I wish to draw with fixed number of xtick. I know "xtick distance" will use fixed distance for xtick, but if data increased, too many xticks will be drawed.
So I wish to use fixed number of xtiks, if domain increase, ticks number will still the same.
I can use "xtick distance" to implement that with formula (max - min)/N, but if domain changed, I need to recalculate it again.

For example, if I want 20 xticks, I can do it like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis y line=middle,axis x line=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$,
    xtick distance=0.6, % 20 ticks (6+6)/20
     xticklabel style={
        rotate=90,
        anchor=near xticklabel,
      }]
    \addplot[blue,mark=none]
    plot[domain=-2*pi:2*pi,samples=80] (\x,{sin(\x r)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
How can I get such a effect automatically (just like "xtick number=20")?

Comment: There is `try min ticks`,  but it doesn't do exactly what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here there are three new keys to help you:

The first just eases your pain by doing the calculation for you:

```
xtick calc distance={20}{-6}{6}
```

Here the parameters are the number of ticks, x min and x max.

**Important:** for the next two you must move `domain=...` from `plot[...]` to `\begin{axis}[...]`. It must be before the new keys. Without this they will not work. The reason: the domain must be known, before `xtick distance` can be calculated.

Additionally adding `domain` to `plot[...]` can be done, which will change the domain for the plot. But then you can instead use the first key.

The second and third key both take the number of ticks as thier parameter.

With

```
xtick auto distance={20}
```

the `xtick distance` will be calculated based on the domain. But this may lead to odd values for the ticks (in your example 0.63, 1.26, ...).

The third key rounds the values for the domain before calculating `xtick distance`.

```
xtick auto distance={20}
```

In your example this leads to the values 0.6, 1.2, ... for the ticks.

The code:

**Edit:** improved the code a bit

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
% calculate xtick distance
% #1: number of ticks,
% #2: pgf math funktion to apply to domain min and max (e.g.: round)
%     may be left empty
\newcommand{\pgfplots@calc@xtick@distance}[2]{%
    \edef\@tempa{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/domain}}%
    \expandafter\pgfplots@@calc@xtick@distance\@tempa:#1:#2\@@ppend%
    \pgfkeys{/pgfplots/xtick distance=\xtickdist}%
}

% splits value of 'domain', calculates distance (stored in '\xtickdist')
\@ifundefined{pgfplots@@calc@xtick@distance}{%
    \def\pgfplots@@calc@xtick@distance#1:#2:#3:#4\@@ppend{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xtickdist}{abs(#4(#1) - #4(#2)) / #3}%
    }%
}{%
    % error message in case '\pgfplots@@calc@xtick@distance' is already defined
    \@latex@error{Command \string\pgfplots@@calc@xtick@distance\space
                  already defined.}\@eha
}

\pgfkeys{%
    % #1: number of ticks, #2: x min, #3:x max
    /pgfplots/xtick calc distance/.code n args={3}{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xtickdist}{abs(#3 - #2) / #1}%
        \pgfkeys{/pgfplots/xtick distance=\xtickdist}%
    },
    % #1: number of ticks
    /pgfplots/xtick auto distance/.code={%
        \pgfplots@calc@xtick@distance{#1}{}%
    },
    % #1: number of ticks
    /pgfplots/xtick round distance/.code={%
        \pgfplots@calc@xtick@distance{#1}{round}%
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis y line=middle,axis x line=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$,
    domain=-2*pi:2*pi,
    xtick round distance={20},
%    xtick auto distance={20},
%    xtick calc distance={20}{-6}{6},
%    xtick distance=0.6, % 20 ticks (6+6)/20
%    try min ticks=20,
     xticklabel style={
        rotate=90,
        anchor=near xticklabel,
      }]
    \addplot[blue,mark=none]
    plot[samples=80] (\x,{sin(\x r)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why the `\newcommand`s?

Comment: @percusse just in case. If I accidentally redefine a macro already defined within the depths of `pgfplots`, this gives a clear error message.

Comment: why not then use `\newcommand` already instead of `\def`?

Comment: @percusse `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/domain}` gives, for example, `-2pi:2pi` back (with the colon). The `\def\...#1:#2...` splits this into 2 parameters (with `\def` it's possible to define delimiters). This can't be done with `\newcommand`.

Comment: Just parse the input inside your command instead

Comment: @percusse ok, how?

Comment: Either xparse' `\Split<..>` or `\def\mysplitter#1:#2:#3{\let...\def etc.}` or use `\@ifundefined` without `\newcommand`

Comment: @percusse IMO, 'xparse' is a bit overkill here. But you convinced me using `\@ifundefined', since an already existing command won't be overwritten (although it requires additional code, if one wants a proper erro message). I edited my answer.